# Not able to print more than five lines in App for Office 2013 Excel

Tags: json, excel

I am using App for Office 2013 for printing data in Excel spreadsheet.
So far, I am able to print some rows using my JSON data, but not able to print a large data like ten rows. Code is:

```
function writeData(rows) {   var myTable = new Office.TableData();
    //   myTable.headers = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U"];

    myTable.rows = rows;

    // Set the myTable in the document.
    Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(
      myTable,
      { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Table },
      function (asyncResult) {
      }
    );
}
```

Comment: Are you using interop?

Comment: What do you mean you are not able to print large data like ten rows? Do you get an error? What happens?

Comment: No, i was using App for Ofice 2013 project.

Comment: I was getting this error because the number of columns in each rows were not same.